# Python display image - AttributeError

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, python-2.x

Hi I just got a Raspberry Pi, and I'm working on some very simple code here. What I'm trying to do is to capture an image and display it.

```
import PIL
import Image
import picamera
camera = picamera.PiCamera()
camera.capture("image.jpg")
im = Image.open("image.jpg")
im.show()
```

There was no error, but the image would not show up.

I checked the file, the picture was taken, so no problem on that part of the code.

Would really like some help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is case-sensitive. You are importing `Image` so use it.

Change `image` to `Image` in `im = image("image.jpg")`
It'll become:

```
from PIL import Image
import picamera
camera = picamera.PiCamera()
camera.capture("image.jpg")
im = Image.open("image.jpg")
im.show()
```

Comment: I was about to edit the question when you answered! Much appreciated, I found this error and I changed it. Now is says: TypeError:'module' object is not callable

Comment: use PIL.Image or make proper import from PIL import Image

Comment: Now it has become: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Image'

Comment: also you missed quotes here camera.capture(image.jpg), use camera.capture("image.jpg")

Comment: And if I use 'from PIL import Image' is becomes "NameError: name 'PIL' is not defined"

Comment: update the code with what you've changed, it's pretty hard to guess

Comment: and did you install PIL? it works fine on my Raspberry

Comment: Yes I did install PIL, and it did not give me an error importing PIL.

Comment: oh my bad, i missed open. It supposed to be im = PIL.Image.open("image.jpg")

Comment: I was able to run without error with Image.open but nothing happened... image did not show up. And got AttributeError if I used PIL.Image.open

Comment: Still scratching my head - but anyway, you really helped a lot. Much appreciated.